# Please explain what the sentence REPLACE(tablecolumn,CHR(13),'') really mean in db2 (Native SQL)

Tags: db2, native-sql

Please help me in understanding what does the below code really mean?

```
CASE WHEN REPLACE(tablename.columnname,CHR(13),'') <> '' 
THEN 
  REPLACE(tablename.columnname,CHR(13), '')
ELSE 
  REPLACE(tablename.columnname,CHR(13),'')
```

For your reference:

```
tablename.columname = mara.matnr
```

`mara` is a table and `matnr` is a field name in the table `Mara`.

Answer (score 0):

`CHR(13)` is a carriage return, sometimes seen in text fields.  I've worked on a number of solutions where I had to strip those out of strings so that when I displayed them on a reporting front-end (such as Excel), they didn't go to a new row.  That is essentially what this code is doing - removing carriage returns by replacing them with a zero-length string.

The `CASE` expression you reference above is essentially useless, since it is using the same expression in both the `THEN` and `ELSE`. The entire script could be rewritten as:

```
REPLACE(tablename.columnname,CHR(13),'')
```